# visibility:hidden Vs visibility:collapse

Tags: css

In CSS, what is the difference between visibility:hidden and visibility:collapse

They are given to be separate in W3Schools, but I see no difference in their output.

I have tried it in Google Crome.

Comment: Don't rely on W3Schools, the site has a lot of errors and inaccuracies.  And despite the name has nothing to do with the W3C (see: http://w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`hidden` means the element is invisible, though the *space* it takes on the page remains.

`collapsed` means the element is invisible, AND the *space* it takes on the page is gone, but it only applies to table elements (otherwise, just like `hidden`).

See the details on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/visibility).

Comment: +1 for precise definitions

Comment: I don't think that's true, is it? display:none gives the functionality you're describing. visibility:collapse is a similar thing with table layouts, but not the same. If you apply it to non-table elements, it works like visibility:hidden.

Comment: @pdr - Thanks for the correction, quite right. Answer updated and link to source added.

Comment: Both of them are giving the same output to me in Crome, what's wrong?

Comment: @myselfpoddar - Probably Chrome (unless you are using an element that is not a _table_ element). As mentioned in the linked documentation, support is not universal.

Comment: Right now this answer makes it seem as if `collapsed` is only applicable to table elements and that is not true and I also that is not your intention. Thus to be more clear, I think, it should say "`collapsed` is the same as `hidden` for non `table` elements. For `table` elements it is `hidden` plus the space it takes is gone.